# Порядок выполнения функций

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть GameObject. В нем 2 компонента: MainLevelSetting и RespawnController.

Классе MainLevelSetting:

```
 void Start () {
        Debug.Log( "Start MainLevelSetting" );
        GetComponent<RespawnController>().RespawnHero();
    }
```

И в RespawnController:

```
void Start () {
Debug.Log( "Start RespawnController" );
}

public void RespawnHero(){
   Debug.Log( "RespawnHero" );
}
```

Поле запуска, в консоле отоброжается:

"Start MainLevelSetting"
"RespawnHero" 
"Start RespawnController"

То есть сначала вызывается метод класса, а потом только метод инициализируется!

Где ошибка и как исправить?

Comment: Что же делать? Или как мне по другому сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел статью про порядок событий http://habrahabr.ru/post/147315/ и понял что я заблуждался!

Start вызывается не при инициализации класс( я думал что это аналог конструктора из С++ ), а

> **До первого обновления кадров**
>
> Start: вызывается перед прорисовкой
> первого фрейма, только если сценарий
> определён.

А (может не совсем правильно выражусь) аналог является функция:

> Первая загрузка сцены
>
> Эти функции вызываются, когда сцена стартует (по
> одному разу для каждого объекта в
> кадре).
>
> Awake: Эта функция **всегда вызывается до начала любых функций**, а также сразу после инициализации префаба.

То есть то что нужно!!

Но для моего случая больше подошло переделать методы.

Так что думаю ответ на вопрос найден! =)